# Laravel Collection Issuing SQL Query

Tags: php, laravel

This might be my limited understanding of laravel, but I am stuck on a logic of implementing a method available on Laravel Collections.

I have a `users` table and a `subscriptions` table with one-to-one relationship between a `User` and a `Subscription`.

What I want to achieve is a collection of `users` grouped by a column from the `subscriptions` table.

The structure of `subscription` table is

```
|Subscriptions|
-----------------
| user_id | year | ... | created_at |
```

I have a relationship created on `User` model `subscription` which creates a one-to-one relationship.

I am able to fetch all the `users` with their associated `subscriptions` using the query below.

```
$users = User::with('subscription')->get()
```

Since I am returned with a collection of users at `$users`, I am trying to group it based on `year`

```
$groupedUsers = $users->groupBy('year');
```

But the problem here is, it is issuing `n`SQL queries which is not my intention. When I am using `groupBy()` with collections, doesn't it mean that it would operate the logic within itself (array) rather than more SQL Queries??

Also specifying a callback function isn't helping either. I think the logic that I am implementing here with my callback function doesnt really satisfy what I am trying to achieve.  There must be something that I don't understand or must be doing it wrong.

```
$user = User::with(['subscription' => function($query){
            $query->groupBy('year');
        }])->get();
```

Comment: what's your Laravel version ?

Comment: what was the error then ?

Comment: There were no errors. The application was issuing too many Query Requests slowing it down.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for such a silly question. Just figured it out.

```
$groupedUsers = $users->groupBy('subscription.year');
```

Would do the trick. I am posting it as an answer if someone is stuck with such question.

What what I still don't understand is why `$users->groupBy('year')` was issuing the sql queries. If someone can point out some reading resources, it would be highly appreciated.